# Length-parameterized passed object to type-bound procedure has gfortran complain

Tags: fortran, gfortran, type-definition

I'm learning Fortran and I'd like to encapsulate an array and a subroutine in a type. The problem appears to be in the type definition of the self-object.

This is the minimal test case I came up with:

```
module testing
  implicit none

  type test(para)
    integer, len :: para
    real, dimension(para) :: weights

  contains
    procedure :: testing => testing_test
  end type
contains
  subroutine testing_test(self)
    class(test(*)) :: self
  end subroutine
end module
```

Compiling this with gfortran raises this error:

```
module_test.f08:9:23:

  procedure :: testing => testing_test
          1
Error: Argument ‘self’ of ‘testing_test’ with PASS(self) at (1) must be of the derived-type ‘test’
```

It works when the array-length is fixed (so `type%para` doesn't exist)

Is what I'm trying to do (type with array of variable size and bound procedure) plain impossible or am I missing something regarding dummy argument definition?

Comment: It's probably a compiler bug. What version of gfortran are you using? PDT was included by gfortran recently, and there are still some bugs left.

Comment: result of `gfortran --version`: `GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.1.1 20180712 (Red Hat 8.1.1-5)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Rodrigo for the idea, I finally found this bug (and patch):
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82943

To fix the issue, download the source, apply the mentioned patch and compile your own gfortran. (Or wait until it's in the repositories)

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer but may provide a solution for some. `gfortran-10` still has the same problem. However `flang-7` compiles this example and it is [available](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flang) for Ubuntu since 19.10, and maybe other OS:es.

Comment: There were so many flangs that this is a mess to me. Is this the "new flang" or the "old flang" from here https://fosdem.org/2020/schedule/event/llvm_flang/attachments/slides/3839/export/events/attachments/llvm_flang/slides/3839/flang_llvm_frontend.pdf ?

Comment: On https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/flang it says "flang (20190329-5)" so should be "old" flang. But not sure.

Answer (score 1):

A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682967/3157076) points to a bug report and patch for gfortran.  It is worth saying, though, that this is standard Fortran (2003) code.

What we have here is a type-bound procedure with passed-object dummy argument.  The main restrictions of such an argument are that it is a:

- scalar,
- nonallocatable,
- nonpointer object,
- with all length-type parameters assumed.

Further, as the type is extensible the passed-object dummy argument must be polymorphic.

For the example of the question, all of the conditions are met.