# parameterised procedure in derived types

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I am trying to write a small module that makes derived type `vector`, 
however, when I compile with gcc10.1 I get an error

```
overload1.f95:10:14:

   10 |      procedure :: ciao
      |              1
Error: Argument â of â with PASS(sh) at (1) must be of the derived-type â
overload1.f95:30:5:
```

Looking in internet I found no explicit example of using parameterised types in 
type-bind procedure. Anybody has a clue on where is the error? (below the small code)

```
module mat
implicit none

type  vector(k, ndim)
 integer, kind :: k=KIND(4)
 integer, len  :: ndim
 real(kind = k), dimension(ndim) :: v
contains
 procedure :: ciao
end type vector

contains

subroutine ciao(sh,a)
class (vector(KIND(4),ndim)) :: sh
real(kind=8) :: a
a = 1d0
end subroutine ciao


end module mat
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
use mat
type( vector(4,10) ) :: A
A%v(1) =  1d0
A%V(2) =  2d0
A%v(3) =  3d0
write(*,*) A

end program
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: Your use of `KIND(4)` is quite peculiar. do you really want to get the kind of the default integer? In that case I would use `KIND(1)` to be less confusing. Also, be aware that `kind=8` is ugly and not portable and may be incompatible with `1d0`.

Comment: At the very least, you have an error in your code with `class (vector(KIND(4),ndim)) :: sh` (you haven't declared `ndim`, and instead you need the length parameter to be assumed `*`), but I suspect you are running in to the problem in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52678258/3157076).

Comment: I've marked as a duplicate on the basis of the GCC bug report in answer to the linked question. This doesn't address the fault in the code, but even correcting that error you'll come across the GCC bug.

Comment: thanks francescalus, this is exactly what I would like to do. I am surprised that in bugzilla they propose a patch, but gcc10.1 has the same problem